# Decoder Expansion. Constructing a 6-to-64 decoder from 3-to-8 decoder

Tags: digital-logic, circuit-analysis, decoder

I just started to study decoders and multiplexers and I saw this task which I'm not sure how it's done. Can you please explain me (solution attached): Using the decoder DEK 3/8, construct the decoder DEK 6/64.

[image]

---

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The input of the decoders is A[5:0]. A[5:0] has 64 possible values "000000", "000001", "000010", ..., "111111". The first three binary digits A[5:3] go to the first decoder. The last 3 binary digits A[2:0] go to the second row decoders. Each of the second row decoder *would* activate one of its output for each A input, but only the one whose Chip Select (CS) is activated by the first decoder actually *will* activate its output. Thus only one output in total is activated at a time.

Consider for example the case of A=10. In binary that is A[5:0]="001010". Split that into two parts, you get A[5:3] = "001" and A[2:0] = "010". The first decoder gets "001" (1 decimal) in its input and activates output 1. This is routed to the chip select input of decoder (2). Decoder (2) has "010" (2 decimal) in its input and activates output 2. None of the other decoders activate their output because their CS is inactive. And what a surprise: there's "10" (ten) marked at the output pin 2 of the second decoder.

Comment: What do you mean by A[5:0], A[2:0] etc...

Comment: A[5:0] means 6 signals: A5, A4, A3, A2, A1, A0. It's a fairly common designation. A[5:3] means A5, A4 and A3; A[2:0] means A2, A1 and A0. So A[y:x] means signals "from" Ay "to" Ax

Comment: I think I'm beginning to understand, but I still don't understand the inputs for the first decoder. Why is it written A5---A2, A4---A1, A3---A0? Why isn't it simply A5, A4, A3, and for the second row decoders, A2, A1, A0?

Comment: The component named "DEK 3/8" is same and unaltered wherever it's put. From the component's perspective it just has 3 inputs which it treats kind of like a 3-bit binary number and activates one of its outputs. But the part itself doesn't know which signals from the system are connected to its inputs. It just does happily its business without regard to the larger things happening in the system around it. In this case someone designed that component and it can be used no matter what the input signals are. The names of the pins in the component are just decorative to help remember which does what

Comment: What is the difference between the first and the second photo I posted?

Comment: No technical difference, only it's impossible for the schematic engineer to know if the inputs are in order A2,A1,A0 or in order A0,A1,A2 which is prone to errors. Note that in "real" components (74HC138) the inputs are often named A, B and C and not with letters and subindexes. http://www.piclist.com/images/www/hobby_elec/gif/pic6_342.gif

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20586/discussion-between-a6tech-and-pkp).